# Empty words in regular languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, regular-expressions

Let $L_1,L_2$ be any $\Sigma$-Languages, with $l_1\in L_1, l_2\in L_2$

If I have a regular Language $L(l_1(l_2l_1)^*l_2)$ would the word $\omega=l_2$ be recognized? I'm confused because if $\epsilon \in L_1$ then $l_1$could be $\epsilon$, then $L(l_1(l_2l_1)^*l_2)$ would recognize the word with $(l_1 = \epsilon) *((l_2l_1)^0=\epsilon)*l_2 = \omega$

I think this is wrong but I don't know why.

Comment: Please pick a better title, this one does nothing to distinguish your question.

Comment: Try proving your claim.

Comment: I don't know how i would approach a proof like that

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your argument.

Comment: So the empty word would be recognized by my Language? Then, would $(L(l_1))^+$ recognize it?